# Formatting a \section* like a normal \section

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I'm having trouble understanding how to format a `\section*` to make it look like a `\section` (without the section number, of course).

Here is the code which the package I have to use uses for formatting `\sections`:

```
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{
   \refstepcounter{#1}\edef\@svsec{\csname the#1\endcsname.\hskip 0.6em}
       \begingroup \ifnum #2=1\bf\centering
          {\interlinepenalty \@M
          \large{\@svsec #8}\par}\else\ifnum #2=2\bf
          \noindent{\interlinepenalty \@M \@svsec #8\par}\else
            \it
            \ifnum #2=3
            \noindent{\interlinepenalty \@M \@svsec #8\par}
            \else\@hangfrom{\hskip\parindent}{\interlinepenalty \@M
             \@svsec #8\par}\fi\fi\fi\endgroup
       \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}\addcontentsline
         {toc}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname} #7}
     \@tempskipa #5\relax
     \@xsect{\@tempskipa}}
```

It looks like this:

[image: \section]

A `\section*` currently looks like this:

[image: \section*]

I have tried using `\@ssect` but I think that's the wrong command, and I wasn't able to find documentation that made clear to me what I need to do.

Edit: The whole package in question:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% File:     INTERSPEECH2016.sty
%
% Usage:    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%           \usepackage{INTERSPEECH2016}
%
%           Or for LaTeX 2.09:
% Usage:    \documentstyle[...,INTERSPEECH2016,...]{article}
%
% Purpose:
%
% Style file for INTERSPEECH 2016 Conference.
% Modified from previous INTERSPEECH conferences
% Features:
%    - correct page size (175mm x 226mm)
%    - use Times-Roman font as default font (roman font) in order to achieve
%      best quality on paper and screen
%    - two-column format
%    - boldfaced, numbered, and centered section headings
%    - correct subsection and subsubsection headings
%    - use \title{xx} for title, will be typeset all uppercase
%    - use \name{xx} for author name(s) only, will be typeset in italics
%    - use \address{xx} for one address of all authors
%    - use \twoauthors{author1}{address1}{author2}{address2}
%         for two (or more) authors with two separate addresses
%    - note: no need for \author nor \date
%    - optional: can use \thanks{xx} within \name or \twoauthors,
%         asterisk is not printed after name nor in footnote
%    - optional: can use \sthanks{xx} after each name within \name or
%         \twoauthors if different thanks for each author,
%         footnote symbol will appear for each name and footnote
%    - optional: use \ninept to typeset text in 9 pt; default is 10pt.
%
% Example of use for one or more authors at a common address and
%    common support. For distinct support acknowledgments,
%    use \sthanks{xx} after each name.
%
%                 \documentstyle[INTERSPEECH2016]{article}
%                 \title{Title of the paper}
%                 \name{John E. Speaker and Jack F. Listener
%                       \thanks{This work was supported by...}}
%                 \address{Common address, department \\
%                          City, etc \\
%                          optional e-mail address}
%
%                 \begin{document}
%  OPTIONAL -->     \ninept            <-- OPTIONAL, for nine pt only
%                   \maketitle
%                   \begin{abstract}
%                     This is the abstract for my paper.
%                   \end{abstract}
%                         .
%                   Insert text of paper
%                         .
%                 \end{document}
%
% Example of use for two authors at two distinct addresses with only
%    one support acknowledgment. For distinct support acknowledgments,
%    use \sthanks{xx} after each name.
%
%                 \documentstyle[INTERSPEECH2016]{article}
%                 \title{Title of the paper}
%                 \twoauthors{John Doe
%                       \thanks{This work was supported by...}}
%                            {Doe's address, department \\
%                             City, etc \\
%                             optional e-mail address}
%                            {Judy Smith}
%                            {Smith's address, department \\
%                             City, etc \\
%                             optional e-mail address}
%
%                 \begin{document}
%  OPTIONAL -->     \ninept            <-- OPTIONAL, for nine pt only
%                   \maketitle
%                   \begin{abstract}
%                     This is the abstract for my paper.
%                   \end{abstract}
%                         .
%                   Insert text of paper
%                         .
%                 \end{document}
%
%
% PLEASE REPORT ANY BUGS to  panayiotis.georgiou@gmail.com
% 
% Author:  Stephen Martucci  -- martucci@cdg.nj.nec.com
% Modifications: Jyri Huopaniemi -- jyri.huopaniemi@nokia.com
%                Matti Karjalainen -- matti.karjalainen@hut.fi
%                Panayiotis Georgiou -- panayiotis.georgiou@gmail.com
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%change default font to Times-Roman
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
  {section}%
  {1}%
  {\z@}%
  {-\baselineskip}%
  {0.5\baselineskip}%
  {}}%

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
  {subsection}%
  {2}%
  {\z@}%
  {-\baselineskip}%
  {0.5\baselineskip}%
  {}}%

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection
  {subsubsection}%
  {3}%
  {\z@}%
  {-\baselineskip}%
  {0.5\baselineskip}%
  {}}%

% these are the A4 settings
\oddsidemargin -0.20 in % -0.31in
\evensidemargin -0.20 in % -0.31in
\topmargin 0truept
\headheight 0truept
\footskip 0truept % 0truept
\textheight 235truemm % 226truemm
\textwidth 170truemm % 175truemm
\voffset -41truept % -14truept
\headsep 43truept % 18truept

\twocolumn
\columnsep 10truemm % 8truemm
%% end of A4 settings

%% This is for the US 8.5 x 11 paper size
%%\oddsidemargin  -0.31in
%%\evensidemargin -0.31in
%%
%%\topmargin 0truept
%%\headheight 0truept
%%\headsep 0truept
%%\footheight 0truept % for some reason this was left commented out for is2006
%%\footskip 0truept   % for some reason this was left commented out for is2006
%%\textheight 226truemm
%%\textwidth 175truemm
%%
%%\twocolumn
%%\columnsep 8truemm
%% end of 8.5x11 bit

\pagestyle{empty}
\def\ninept{\def\baselinestretch{0.95}\let\normalsize\small\normalsize}
\def\eightpt{\def\baselinestretch{0.95}\let\normalsize\footnotesize\normalsize}


\def\maketitle{\par
 \begingroup
 \def\thefootnote{}
 \def\@makefnmark{\hbox
 to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
 \if@twocolumn
 \twocolumn[\@maketitle]
 \else \newpage
 \global\@topnum\z@ \@maketitle \fi\@thanks
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \let\maketitle\relax
 \let\@maketitle\relax
 \gdef\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}\gdef\@@savethanks{}%
 \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}

\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \null
 %\vskip 2em \begin{center}
 \vskip 1em \begin{center}
 {\large \bf \@title \par} \vskip 1.5em {\large \lineskip .5em
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@name \\ \@address
 \end{tabular}\par} \end{center}
 \par
 \vskip 1.5em}

\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{\Large{#1}}}
\def\name#1{\gdef\@name{{\em #1}\\}}
\def\address#1{\gdef\@address{#1}}
\gdef\@title{{Title of paper}}
\gdef\@name{{\em Name of author}\\}
\gdef\@address{Address - Line 1 \\
               Address - Line 2 \\
               Address - Line 3}

\let\@@savethanks\thanks
\def\thanks#1{\gdef\thefootnote{}\@@savethanks{#1}}
\def\sthanks#1{\gdef\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\@@savethanks{#1}}

\def\twoauthors#1#2#3#4{\gdef\@address{}
   \gdef\@name{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        {\em #1} \\ \\
        #2\relax
   \end{tabular}\hskip 0.3in\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        {\em #3} \\ \\
        #4\relax
\end{tabular}}}

\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{
   \refstepcounter{#1}\edef\@svsec{\csname the#1\endcsname.\hskip 0.6em}
       \begingroup \ifnum #2=1\bf\centering
          {\interlinepenalty \@M
          \large{\@svsec #8}\par}\else\ifnum #2=2\bf
          \noindent{\interlinepenalty \@M \@svsec #8\par}\else
            \it
            \ifnum #2=3
            \noindent{\interlinepenalty \@M \@svsec #8\par}
            \else\@hangfrom{\hskip\parindent}{\interlinepenalty \@M
             \@svsec #8\par}\fi\fi\fi\endgroup
       \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}\addcontentsline
         {toc}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname} #7}
     \@tempskipa #5\relax
     \@xsect{\@tempskipa}}

\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5{\@tempskipa #3\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
     %\begingroup #4\@hangfrom{\hskip #1}{\interlinepenalty \@M #5\par}\endgroup
     % The IEEE does not block indent the section title text, it flows like normal
     \begingroup \noindent #4{\relax{\hskip #1}{\interlinepenalty \@M #5\@@par}}\endgroup
  % svsechd swallows the trailing space, protect it with \mbox{}
  \else \def\@svsechd{#4{\hskip #1\relax #5\mbox{}}}\fi
  \@xsect{#3}}

\def\abstract{\begin{center}
{\bf \large Abstract\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{2pt}}
\end{center}}
\def\endabstract{\par}

\def\copyrightnotice#1{\gdef\@copyrightnotice{#1}}\let\@copyrightnotice\relax
\def\toappear#1{\gdef\@toappear{#1}}\let\@toappear\relax

%%% Strings for the preprint titlepage footer:

\newif\if@preprint\@preprintfalse
\def\ds@preprint{\@preprinttrue}
\def\ps@preprint{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo\def\@oddhead{}
  \def\@oddfoot{\rlap{\@toappear}\hfil\thepage\hfil
    \llap{\@copyrightnotice}\gdef\@toappear{}\gdef\@copyrightnotice{}}}

\if@preprint\ps@preprint
\else\ps@empty\flushbottom\fi

\def\thebibliography#1{\section{References}\list
 {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

\flushbottom
%%%%% fancyheading included
\def\lhead{\@ifnextchar[{\@xlhead}{\@ylhead}}
\def\@xlhead[#1]#2{\gdef\@elhead{#1}\gdef\@olhead{#2}}
\def\@ylhead#1{\gdef\@elhead{#1}\gdef\@olhead{#1}}

\def\chead{\@ifnextchar[{\@xchead}{\@ychead}}
\def\@xchead[#1]#2{\gdef\@echead{#1}\gdef\@ochead{#2}}
\def\@ychead#1{\gdef\@echead{#1}\gdef\@ochead{#1}}

\def\rhead{\@ifnextchar[{\@xrhead}{\@yrhead}}
\def\@xrhead[#1]#2{\gdef\@erhead{#1}\gdef\@orhead{#2}}
\def\@yrhead#1{\gdef\@erhead{#1}\gdef\@orhead{#1}}

\def\lfoot{\@ifnextchar[{\@xlfoot}{\@ylfoot}}
\def\@xlfoot[#1]#2{\gdef\@elfoot{#1}\gdef\@olfoot{#2}}
\def\@ylfoot#1{\gdef\@elfoot{#1}\gdef\@olfoot{#1}}

\def\cfoot{\@ifnextchar[{\@xcfoot}{\@ycfoot}}
\def\@xcfoot[#1]#2{\gdef\@ecfoot{#1}\gdef\@ocfoot{#2}}
\def\@ycfoot#1{\gdef\@ecfoot{#1}\gdef\@ocfoot{#1}}

\def\rfoot{\@ifnextchar[{\@xrfoot}{\@yrfoot}}
\def\@xrfoot[#1]#2{\gdef\@erfoot{#1}\gdef\@orfoot{#2}}
\def\@yrfoot#1{\gdef\@erfoot{#1}\gdef\@orfoot{#1}}

\newdimen\headrulewidth
\newdimen\footrulewidth
\newdimen\plainheadrulewidth
\newdimen\plainfootrulewidth
\newdimen\headwidth
\newif\if@fancyplain
\def\fancyplain#1#2{\if@fancyplain#1\else#2\fi}

% Command to reset various things in the headers:
% a.o.  single spacing (taken from setspace.sty)
% and the catcode of ^^M (so that epsf files in the header work if a
% verbatim crosses a page boundary)
\def\fancy@reset{\restorecr
 \def\baselinestretch{1}%
 \ifx\undefined\@newbaseline% NFSS not present; 2.09 or 2e
  \ifx\@currsize\normalsize\@normalsize\else\@currsize\fi%
 \else% NFSS (2.09) present
  \@newbaseline%
 \fi}

% Initialization of the head and foot text.

\headrulewidth 0.4pt
\footrulewidth\z@
\plainheadrulewidth\z@
\plainfootrulewidth\z@

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl\rightmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\leftmark}}
%  i.e. empty on ``plain'' pages, \rightmark on even, \leftmark on odd pages
\chead{}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\rightmark}}
%  i.e. empty on ``plain'' pages, \leftmark on even, \rightmark on odd pages
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}

% Put together a header or footer given the left, center and
% right text, fillers at left and right and a rule.
% The \lap commands put the text into an hbox of zero size,
% so overlapping text does not generate an errormessage.

\def\@fancyhead#1#2#3#4#5{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset\vbox{\hbox
{\rlap{\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2\strut}}\hfill
\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\centering#3\strut}\hfill
\llap{\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4\strut}}}\headrule}}#5}


\def\@fancyfoot#1#2#3#4#5{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset\vbox{\footrule
\hbox{\rlap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2\strut}}\hfill
\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\centering#3\strut}\hfill
\llap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4\strut}}}}}#5}

\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}

\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
\vskip-0.3\normalbaselineskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
\hrule\@width\headwidth\@height\footrulewidth\vskip0.3\normalbaselineskip}}

\def\ps@fancy{%
\@ifundefined{@chapapp}{\let\@chapapp\chaptername}{}%for amsbook
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\def\sectionmark##1{\markboth
{\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@
 \thesection\hskip 1em\relax \fi ##1}}{}}%
\def\subsectionmark##1{\markright {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
 \thesubsection\hskip 1em\relax \fi ##1}}}%
{\def\chaptermark##1{\markboth {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
 \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}{}}
\def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
 \thesection. \ \fi ##1}}}}%
\csname ps@headings\endcsname % use \ps@headings defaults if they exist
\ps@@fancy
\gdef\ps@fancy{\@fancyplainfalse\ps@@fancy}%
\headwidth\textwidth}
\def\ps@fancyplain{\ps@fancy \let\ps@plain\ps@plain@fancy}
\def\ps@plain@fancy{\@fancyplaintrue\ps@@fancy}
\def\ps@@fancy{%
\def\@mkboth{\protect\markboth}%
\def\@oddhead{\@fancyhead\@lodd\@olhead\@ochead\@orhead\@rodd}%
\def\@oddfoot{\@fancyfoot\@lodd\@olfoot\@ocfoot\@orfoot\@rodd}%
\def\@evenhead{\@fancyhead\@rodd\@elhead\@echead\@erhead\@lodd}%
\def\@evenfoot{\@fancyfoot\@rodd\@elfoot\@ecfoot\@erfoot\@lodd}%
}
\def\@lodd{\if@reversemargin\hss\else\relax\fi}
\def\@rodd{\if@reversemargin\relax\else\hss\fi}

\let\latex@makecol\@makecol
\def\@makecol{\let\topfloat\@toplist\let\botfloat\@botlist\latex@makecol}
\def\iftopfloat#1#2{\ifx\topfloat\empty #2\else #1\fi}
\def\ifbotfloat#1#2{\ifx\botfloat\empty #2\else #1\fi}
\def\iffloatpage#1#2{\if@fcolmade #1\else #2\fi}
```

Comment: Which package do you use?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added it to the question. It's not on CTAN.

Comment: I've used the `traditional` `\@ssect` from `article` class,see the possible answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, I am very new to the more advanced TeX world so I am struggleing a bit currently. Thanks for your help, I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the centered `\section*` version with code from `latex.ltx` (as is used in standard classes)

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
   \refstepcounter{#1}\edef\@svsec{\csname the#1\endcsname.\hskip 0.6em}
       \begingroup \ifnum #2=1\bf\centering
          {\interlinepenalty \@M
          \large{\@svsec #8}\par}\else\ifnum #2=2\bf
          \noindent{\interlinepenalty \@M \@svsec #8\par}\else
            \itshape
            \ifnum #2=3
            \noindent{\interlinepenalty \@M \@svsec #8\par}
            \else\@hangfrom{\hskip\parindent}{\interlinepenalty \@M
             \@svsec #8\par}\fi\fi\fi\endgroup
       \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}\addcontentsline
         {toc}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname} #7}
     \@tempskipa #5\relax
     \@xsect{\@tempskipa}}


\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \@tempskipa #3\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #4{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #1}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M \centering#5\@@par}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{#4{\hskip #1\relax\centering#5}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#3}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\blindtext[1]

\section*{Foobar}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: uh, the font for `\section*` looks larger than the regular one.  doubt that it's intentional ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton I got around it by simply adding `\large` around `#5`. That worked in my case.